# Откуда сообщение пришло (вопрос по Discord.Py)

Tags: python, discord.py

Всем привет!
Вопрос такой по библиотеке Discord для Python. Как известно, если дискорд-бот подключен, то он имеет возможности отслеживать активность пользователей группы в Дискорд. В случае моего вопроса в ответ на то, что пользователь написал и отправил сообщение в Дискорде, вызывается функция ***on_message(message)***, в качестве аргумента имеет класс, содержащий всю информацию о сообщении (его текст, кем отправлено и т.д.). Так вот, вопрос в чём - Как я могу отследить из какого именно текстового канала было отправлено сообщение (именно Channel_id)? В атрибутах класса ***message*** такого нет (есть название канала, и мне, получается надо по названию найти ID, а если есть одинаковые названия.........). Просто не хочется, чтобы бот реагировал вообще на все сообщения, будучи "расквартированным" на канале. Ладно я, я могу сам залогинить его именно на нужный канал, но для вероятного пользователя хочется поменьше головной боли. И, кстати, может находил кто руководство к этой библиотеке на русском языке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если открыть документацию: [тык](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#message)

То в классе `Message` можно увидеть атрибут `channel`, который может быть одним из этих классов: `TextChannel, Thread, DMChannel, GroupChannel`.

У каждого из них есть атрибут `id`, поэтому можно спокойно сделать так:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    channel_id = message.channel.id
```

Если вам нужен конкретно класс `TextChannel`, то есть обычные текстовые каналы на сервере, можно сделать проверку:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.TextChannel):
        channel_id = message.channel.id
```

Comment: попробую этот метод

Comment: атрибут channel - это вроде именно текстовое название канала (например, "Общий"), но я попробую

Comment: @НикитозСаныч

'Перевод' из документации:

"Это `TextChannel` или `Thread`, с которого было отправлено сообщение. Может быть `DMChannel` или `GroupChannel`, если это личное сообщение." Это не может быть названием канала.

Comment: вот это абсолютно верный ответ (вот самый первый код). Я от чего-то не задумывался, что у классов атрибуты тоже могут быть классами (и иметь свои атрибуты). Всё хорошо и понятно